# Android, how to display a list of objects, one per page?

Tags: android, list

I need to implement an Android viewer to display a list of results (from a real estate site web query), which I have in a list property (

```
private List<Estate> estatesList;
```

)

For each item I have one image, one description, one phone number (and some more text fields).
I would like my app to display each result, one per page, and to display the next (or previous) one on a "swipe" (or "fling"?) gesture from user.

The question is: which is the right approach? Should I use a "ListActivity"? If so, how do I bind it to my objects list? Or should I better use a ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ListActivity` is a special kind of `Activity` that contains a `ListView`. Basically, a `ListActivity` does just provide an easier API to build an Activity around a `ListView`. Nevertheless, this class is a bit useless and tends to be less interesting on the long run. You should better use an normal `Activity` (I mean build your own class that extends `Activity`) and add a `ListView` in it.

You should learn how to use a `ListAdapter` to feed your `ListView` with some data (the list model in MVC). You got two main alternatives : using a memory adapter, or use a CursorAdapter that will pick data directly from a database.

There are many tutorials on the web to start learning `ListViews`. [This](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327) could be a good one, among many many others.

Regards,
 steff

Answer (score 0):

A ListActivity is just an activity that manages a ListView, so that doesn't change much. If you want to swipe sideways, you'll have to use a [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) instead.

For the swipe, you can detect it using a GestureDetector and your view's onTouchListener. The ListView can be scrolled either using setPosition(int position) (jumps to a given position) or [smoothScrollToPosition(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29).

If what you want is something like the home screen, which whole screens scrolling left/right, then you might want to use the [Workspace widget](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Stock/android-launcher-for-sdk/mobi/intuitit/android/stock/launcher/Workspace.java.htm). That widget isn't included in the default API, but the code is freely available :)